# Does the length, breadth and height of a cuboid gets interchange, if we place it on the table differently i.e., with the base having different side?

Tags: geometry

I was going through the problems of finding ratio of width to length of shapes and Two of the rectangles had their short sides going right to 
left, with the long sides going up and down; the third rectangle 
showed the short sides going up and down and the long sides going 
right to left.
The answers to the problems gave the answers 
as the width always being the short side, and the length always being 
the long side. However, this is not mentioned in the directions.

SO, my question is does the length, breadth, height interchange their values when we place the same 3d object(here cuboid) on its different surface as its base, if yes, why is that?wouldn't it be nice to have a single value of length, breadth and height for any given 3d object, ( here are the images of a cuboid from three different sides of that same cuboid from different angles)
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUJxC.png) [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7r8p.png) [image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHMlH.png)

Also what will happen if one of its sides increases to three times its original size? does the length breadth and heights still remain the same or height and length interchange their values [image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWYp3.png) [image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIV2F.png).If following the convention that the vertical side is always height and the of the remaining two the longest being the length and the short being the breadth also sometimes i saw not being followed like in the 2nd photo [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUMHH.jpg)( the 3"unit side the length and the 4" unit side breadth. If anyone regardless of any field(deep geometrical mathematics to a 10 year old) needs to write l,b,h values after all those figures posted what will their figuring out process maybe? Please clarify in a way i can understand?

Comment: That depends on exactly how **you** define "length", "height", and "breadth".  A lot of people will see no difference between "length" and "breadth" while always assigning "height" to the upward dimension.  Mathematically, there is NO difference.

Comment: @user247327 there is only one way to define length, breadth and height right? What if i define it in the general way? what are the lengths breadths and heights of the above figure, would you mind adding a detalied answer as i am having high lvl of confusion here like wouldn't it be simple if all 3d shapes have single value of lengths, breadth and height why they interchange if we place them with a base on a different side?

Comment: Generally the real. Objects conventions are "LBH", Height/depth is the vertical dimension. And in maths, in two dimensions, usually the longer dimension is considered as length for unknown sides. And for 3D objects if the diagram is given in the question, you have to take the dimensions as indicated. If not, then you are free to choose however you want, there is no Difference in that. Unless you're dealing with rectangular coordinates.